# WinCE device and VS2008 connectivity for debugging and deploying

Tags: windows-ce, visual-studio-2008-sp1, .net-cf-3.5

I have WinCE device and visual studio 2008 project. I want to deploy and debug the project without active sync (I am using Win7 as my developemnt machine). I have established the connection between my device and developemnt machine using network cable. When I ran Conmanclient2.exe and CMAccept.exe from windows directory of my device I still got the error when I perform Test Connection from VS2008 that

> Active sync bootstrapper failed. Please connect real device...

I have set my device IP - 10.0.0.1

My dev machine IP - 10.0.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to configure the device to not use Active Sync as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228708%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: I have already did it but still there is some problem. The interesting fact is its work as expected on WinXP dev machine but not on Win7 Dev machine.

Comment: Stupid question: why do you not want to use ActiveSync (or Mobile Device Center on Windows 7)?

Comment: @Thorsten ActiveSync is an optional component on WinCE devices, it might not be available on the OP's device.

Comment: I was curious, because he said that he *wants* to. If ActiveSync was available for his device, things would be easier if he used that.

Comment: Yes, I was tring to configure it for not to use ActiveSync but when it didn't work on my developer machine with Win7, I switched back to WMDC which is similar to active sync but specially for Win7 and Vista.

Answer (score 0):

Windows mobile 6 classic emulator selection does not fail